# A problem on separabale metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to prove that $R^k$ has a countable dense (any point in $R^k$ is either a limit point of that subset or contains in that subset) subset. Shall I use induction on $k$ ?

Comment: Think: what is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$? How can you _easily_ generalize this to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: For $\Bbb R$ it is $\Bbb Q$. So, for $\Bbb R^k$ it will be set with rational co-ordinates. But how do I prove it ?

Comment: If $(x_1,x_2,...,x_k)$ is a real vector, then you can arbitrarily approximate each coordinate with rational numbers, so we can choose a rational vector $(r_1,...,r_k)$ such that $|x_i-r_i|\lt\frac{\varepsilon}k$. Now it suffices to note that $||\mathscr{x}-\mathscr{r}||_2\le k||\mathscr{x}-\mathscr{r}||_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use induction, you will have to show that a) $\mathbb{R}$ is separable and b) that the product of two separable spaces is again separable.